# Linux server vlc to restream rtsp feed from ip cam

Tags: streaming, vlc, rtsp

Im new i streaming so sorry for stupid questions, I tried to find info in web but nothing seems to work.

What Im trying to do

I have IP Cam that puts out RTSP stream to internet its IP is: rtsp://89.79.16.127:2550
When Im accessing that stream in windows VLC (win xp) every thing works (you can tryit for yourself)

Now I have dedicated linux debian serwer with ip: 109.95.153.133

I want to setup VLC serwer that will grap rtsp feed from camera IP and restream it via my serwer, so I can show that stream on my website (located on that dedicated serwer)

Can You help mi accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VLC, select Open location from clipboard
2. Enter the proper camera url. For example, the axis M7014 streams in H264 so its url will look like `rtsp://Camera-IP/axis-media/media.amp?codec=h264`
3. Enter the login at the prompt or encode it to the rtsp link
    
   rtsp://user:pass@Camera-IP/axis-media/media.amp?codec=INFO.)
   If the stream is playing on the screen it means you support this codec. If not, then you shouldn't try to transcode it. For example, the axis M7014 uses an H264 variant that only quicktime fully supports.
4. The previous steps were to determine if you can transcode or if you should just forward the traffic.
5. Menu-Stream, select your RTSP as a source, then add an RTSP destination and stream. If you cant see the video play you can only forward it to a player that can. beware, some RTSP headers might get tweaked and disable the ability to pause video. I can looking for a fix right now.

Comment: Pt. 4 missing? Look at [edit] below your answer. I made it into list by removing the `)`'s. Suspect pt.4 was supposed to be the `.)` after INFO, but better if you correct it :)